# MAP versus Component-Wise Maximum Marginal

Tags: optimization, posterior, marginal-distribution, extreme-value

Suppose I have the joint distribution:

\begin{align}
p(\mathbf{x}) = p(x_1, ... , x_n)
\end{align}

The maximum a posteriori (MAP) solution is given by:

\begin{align}
\mathbf{x}_{MAP} = \arg \max p(\mathbf{x})
\end{align}

Intuitively I believe that finding the maximums of each marginal should not always correspond to $\mathbf{x}_{MAP}$. That is,

\begin{align}
\mathbf{x}_{MAP_1} \neq \max_{x_1}(p(x_1))\\
\mathbf{x}_{MAP_2} \neq \max_{x_2}(p(x_2)) \\
\vdots \\
\mathbf{x}_{MAP_n} \neq \max_{x_n}(p(x_n)) 
\end{align}

I believe this should be the case, HOWEVER I can't convince myself fully. Every joint distribution I imagine, tends to satisfy this trivially (e.g. the mode of a multi-variate Gaussian, can be found by considering the mode for each of the marginals).

1. Is there/are there counter-examples to prove this point?
2. Or perhaps is my intuition wrong? That is, the mode of the marginals always corresponds to the MAP mode.
3. Are there sources on the internet which explore this issue in depth (since no matter what I Google I cannot find an answer on this)?
4. Are there any conditions to declare when this is / isn't true?

Comment: What is the connection between $p(\boldsymbol{x})$ and $p(x_1)$?

Comment: $\mathbf{x}$ is a vector and its components are given by $x_1, ..., x_n$. Let me know if you need further information, since I may have abused notation here. $p(\mathbf{x})$ is shorthand for the joint distribution

Comment: I'm asking about the connections between the density of the multivariate distribution and each marginal, since the answer depends mainly on that. For example, What is the connection between $p(\boldsymbol{x})$ and $p(x_1)$? if $p(\boldsymbol{x}) =\prod_{i=1}^{n} p(x_{i})$, then the components of the MAP over all is in fact the MAP in each marginal. Otherwise, we can build a counter example.

Comment: The relationship is arbitrary. Hence why I would love to see some counter examples of why the MAP over the joint doesn't necessarily correspond to the individual maximums across each marginal. :)

Comment: I assume you meant $\arg \max$, not $\arg \min$, in your second equation?

Comment: Correct. That has been edited.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following discrete distribution:

$$
\boldsymbol{X} = \begin{cases}
(1,1) & \text{w.p. } 0.3 \\
(1,0) & \text{w.p. } 0.15 \\
(0,1) & \text{w.p. } 0.275 \\
(0,0) & \text{w.p. } 0.275 \\
\end{cases}
$$

Then, 
$$
\boldsymbol{x}_{\text{MAP}} = (1,1)
$$

But
$$
\arg\max p(x_1)= 0 \neq \left(\boldsymbol{x}_{\text{MAP}}\right)_{1}
$$
Since $P(X_1 =1) = 0.45$ and $P(X_1 =0) = 0.55$

Comment: Thanks! (1) I think the second expression is supposed to be $P(X_1 = 0)$? Also (2) Would you happen to know of any additional example(s) involving continuous distributions?

Comment: (1) You are right. I fixed it. (2) I believe such exists, but I'm not sure yet.